# C++: Advice for a Prisoner's Dilemma application

Tags: c++

So, basically I'm making a C++ program for a rather simple prisoner's dilemma game.

In this variation that I've made prisoner B needs to follow what prisoner A did in the previous round. To make it easier here's the code of what I have for now.

```
                    //////////////////////////////////
                    //+--------+---------+---------+//
                    //|Results | Silence | Confess |//<-prisonerB - opponent
                    //+--------+---------+---------+//
                    //|Silence |   3,3   |   0,5   |//
                    //+--------+---------+---------+//
                    //|Confess |   5,0   |   1,1   |//
                    //+--------+---------+---------+//
                    //////////////////////////////////
                    // ^prisonerA - us
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numOfRounds;
    char prisonerA; //us
    char prisonerB; //opponent
    int prisonerAYears;
    int prisonerBYears;
    int round; //num of round
    int i; //counter


    prisonerAYears=0;
    prisonerBYears=0;
    round=1;

    cout<<"Enter the number of rounds you want to play: ";
    cin>>numOfRounds;

while(numOfRounds>0)
{
    numOfRounds=numOfRounds-1;
    cout<<"Game "<<round++<<endl;

    cout<<"What is your decision? Confess or stay Silent?(C/S) : ";
    cin>>prisonerA;


while(round==1)
{
    if ((prisonerA=='C') || (prisonerA=='c')) 
    {
        //prisonerB='C';
        prisonerAYears=prisonerAYears+1;
        prisonerBYears=prisonerBYears+1;
        cout<<"Prisoner A (you) chose: Confess. Prisoner B (the opponent) chose: Confess."<<endl;
        cout<<"Prisoner A (you) is currently in for: "<<prisonerAYears<<" years."<<endl;
        cout<<"Prisoner B (the opponent) is currently in for: "<<prisonerBYears<<" years."<<endl;
    }

    else if((prisonerA=='S') || (prisonerA=='s'))
    {
        //prisonerB='C';
        prisonerAYears=prisonerAYears+0;
        prisonerBYears=prisonerBYears+5;
        cout<<"Prisoner A (you) chose: Silence. Prisoner B (the opponent) chose: Silence."<<endl;
        cout<<"Prisoner A (you) is currently in for: "<<prisonerAYears<<" years."<<endl;
        cout<<"Prisoner B (the opponent) is currently in for: "<<prisonerBYears<<" years."<<endl;
    }
}


}

cout<<"The rounds have come to an end."<<endl<<endl;
cout<<"Prisoner A (you) is currently in for: "<<prisonerAYears<<" years."<<endl;
cout<<"Prisoner B (the opponent) is currently in for: "<<prisonerBYears<<" years."<<endl<<endl;

if(prisonerAYears>prisonerBYears)
{

    cout<<"You have to stay in prison longer. You lose."<<endl;
}
if(prisonerAYears<prisonerBYears)
{

    cout<<"The opponent has to stay in prison longer. You win."<<endl;
}

if(prisonerAYears==prisonerBYears)
{

    cout<<"You both are staying in prison for the same amount of time. Its a tie."<<endl;
}
      return 0;
}
```

I've also made 2 other variations where the opponent always confesses or stays silent. Here's the one where the opponent stays silent.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numOfRounds;
    char prisonerA; 
    char prisonerB; 
    int prisonerAYears;
    int prisonerBYears;
    int round; //broj runde

    prisonerAYears=0;
    prisonerBYears=0;
    round=1;

    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter the number of rounds you want to play: ";
    cin>>numOfRounds;
    cout<<endl;

while(numOfRounds>0)
{
    numOfRounds=numOfRounds-1;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Game "<<round++<<endl;
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"What is your decision? Confess or stay Silent?(C/S) : ";
    cin>>prisonerA;
    cout<<endl;

    if ((prisonerA=='C') || (prisonerA=='c')) 
    {
        prisonerB='S';
        prisonerAYears=prisonerAYears+5;
        prisonerBYears=prisonerBYears+0;
        cout<<"Prisoner A (you) chose: Confess. Prisoner B (the opponent) chose: Confess."<<endl;
        cout<<"Prisoner A (you) is currently in for: "<<prisonerAYears<<" years."<<endl;
        cout<<"Prisoner B (the opponent) is currently in for: "<<prisonerBYears<<" years."<<endl;
    }

    else if((prisonerA=='S') || (prisonerA=='s'))
    {
        prisonerB='S';
        prisonerAYears=prisonerAYears+3;
        prisonerBYears=prisonerBYears+3;
        cout<<"Prisoner A (you) chose: Silence. Prisoner B (the opponent) chose: Confess."<<endl;
        cout<<"Prisoner A (you) is currently in for: "<<prisonerAYears<<" years."<<endl;
        cout<<"Prisoner B (the opponent) is currently in for: "<<prisonerBYears<<" years."<<endl;
    }

}
cout<<endl;
cout<<"The rounds have come to an end."<<endl<<endl;
cout<<"Prisoner A (you) is currently in for: "<<prisonerAYears<<" years."<<endl;
cout<<"Prisoner B (the opponent) is currently in for: "<<prisonerBYears<<" years."<<endl<<endl;

if(prisonerAYears>prisonerBYears)
{

    cout<<"You have to stay in prison longer. You lose."<<endl;
}
if(prisonerAYears<prisonerBYears)
{

    cout<<"The opponent has to stay in prison longer. You win."<<endl;
}

if(prisonerAYears==prisonerBYears)
{

    cout<<"You both are staying in prison for the same amount of time. Its a tie."<<endl;
}
      return 0;
}
```

Those were pretty easy. Now I'm stuck here because I'm not sure how to refer to what prisoner A (or I guess, me) chose in the previous round.

In the code I defined that in the first round, the opponent chooses confess.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone can give me an idea on how to pick up what I said in the previous round so that the opponent follows what i did from then.

If I didn't explain something clearly, please ask so that I try and explain it further.

Comment: Just create a variable and when the round ends, store in it what the prisoner did.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, it would be cool if you separate out the choices made by the other player into a separate function.
Something like:

```
char PrisonerBChoice(char prevPrisonerAChoice){
    // your logic for how B's choice depends on A's
}
```

Put this wherever you want to make a choice.
Regarding how to obtain the previous choices, you could create two variables outside the while loop:

```
char prevChoiceA;
char prevChoiceB;
```

and update these at the end of the while loop, with whatever the computer and the player chose.

Does this make sense?

On a tangent direction, I think what you're trying to create is the standard carrot-stick simulation. So when any one player deviates off the Subgame Perfect Nash Equilibrium, it leads to the Grim-Triggered strategy. You can exactly code this into the PrisonerBChoice function! It can be interesting to see how different functions here ( depicting different kinds of people ) lead to meaningful results.
You could code both PrisonerA's and B's functions and let them run at it on their own and check out the results too! ( Once you have the two new variables and functions, you have everything needed to create this )

Comment: Yes I do get what you mean. Thanks for the suggestion! I will try out what you suggested. To be honest I'm kind of rusty at c++ as I've picked it up again after nearly 2 years.